# Transfer Data between 2 organizational domain

Tags: sql-server, replication

Please consider the following scenario:

Company A manages the IT Infrastructure of Company B. Company A is located in US and has SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition. Company B is located in UK and has SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition.

Company A uses Citrix Platform (Server located in Company B domain) as a secure access gateway.

Now, I would like to replicate data from Company B to Company A. I plan to install SQL Express 2014 on Citrix Platform gateway server and subscribe data from Company B SQL Server 2014.

Can I configure a pull subscription on Company A SQL Server box which will pick up data from Citrix Platform gateway server running SQL Server Express 2014?

Please advise.